# How to backup a unity project on github

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

Can someone help me? I have no idea what to do. If someone could please help me with a step by step process. I have no idea what or if I need to instal something. The only think I know is that I usually lose all my projects so I need a proper way to save them. Btw my knowledge about github is 0

Comment: You may need to set up a proper `.gitignore` file for your repository to make sure the correct files are saved. And if you want to backup the entire GitHub repository, you can use Cloudback: https://github.com/marketplace/cloudback

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, I would learn how to use Git and Github. You can try going here:

https://guides.github.com/

This covers GitHub very well. Considering you are working with Unity, you will want to know what files to put on a repository and what not to expose to the world. The tutorials regarding using a .gitignore file will cover that concept. There really isn't much else you need to know.

As an aside, I would also suggest you check out 
[Unity Hub](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedUnityHub.html) . This lets you upload, track and run analysis on your projects from one location.